# Restrict angular form submit on mobile

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have HTML form with angular validation and it shouldn't be submitted unless `$valid` form state is `true`.

```
<form name="searchForm" action="/Search" method="get" novalidate>
    <input name="keywords" required type="search" ng-model="form.keywords">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="searchForm.$invalid">Go</button>
</form>
```

`ng-disabled` directive prevents from submitting invalid form for desktop or mobile emulator. But if I use screen keyboard on mobile device to submit form I can submit it with `$invalid` state. How to handle this situation with touch devices keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive to handle form submission. The angular way is to trigger the search request to the server via $http or similar, not page reload.

Your current setup is a typical html form, which sends the data to */Search* endpoint via get in submission. Even in desktop browser hitting enter when inside the input will submit the form.

Comment: Unfortunately application architecture doesn't allow to avoid page reload and it's not quite clear how to submit form from Angular handler using only Angular features (without accessing DOM directly)

Comment: You may use $window.location.href inside submit() function to redirect to a different page (and include get parameters into that url). See this plunker for example: http://plnkr.co/edit/IMyHLhFMcVfC4RtoFpi6?p=preview

Comment: It still seems ugly like submitting form using DOM.
So, the only appropriate angular approach is avoid page reloading, correct?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "submitting using DOM". No submission is taking place, only angular (javascript) redirects to a specific url which is based on the data entering. Real "DOM only" submission i would say we have when no javascript is involved (html only).

As angular apps are usually single page apps, so load once and then fetch all subsequent content using ajax, redirecting is no ordinary task.